# HTML submit button to create a paragraph element inside a div and appent form value to the paragraph

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript function that can be used to get the value of an HTML form, create a paragraph inside a div container and input the form value into the created paragraph whenever the submit button is clicked. The javascript code i tried seems not to be responding well.

Note: I don''t want the form to return any value.

Here's the whole HTML and javascript code, the button kept on submitting the form value to the page and not updating the commentBox container.

```
 <div class="chat-popup" id="myForm">
    <form name="commentForm" class="form-container">
        <label for="msg"><b>Comment</b></label>
        <textarea id="myComment" placeholder="Type comment.." name="msg" required></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="lk-btn" onclick="postComment(); return false">Send</button>
        <button class="lk-btn" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

<div id="commentBox" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: white; color: green;"></div>

    function postComment() {
        var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
        p.id = 'com';

        document.getElementById('com').innerHTML = document.getElementById('myComment').value;

        var commentContainer = document.getElementById('commentBox');
        commentContainer.appendChild(paragraph);

        return false;

      }
```

Comment: `p.id` This referencing is wrong as you have named your variable as `paragraph`

Comment: the id was assigned to <p> element created not to the variable itself

Comment: But the variable is  reference to that element and the variable is not named `p` which is undefined. Check browser console for errors

Comment: i would appreciate if anyone has a function that can serve the purpose so i can discard this because it getting really anoying

Comment: And that new `<p>` is not in the `document` at the time you try to use `document.getElementById('com')` either because you don't insert into the document until after that

Comment: i tried using the p.innerHTML directly but it still doesn't work

Comment: Your JavaScript console in the browser should be spitting out errors. If the errors are not there, than click the setting in it to preserve console on navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ommit the whole "id" thing and it's done:

```js
function postComment() {
    var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    paragraph.innerHTML = document.getElementById('myComment').value;

    var commentContainer = document.getElementById('commentBox');
    commentContainer.appendChild(paragraph);

    return false;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-popup" id="myForm">
    <form name="commentForm" class="form-container">
        <label for="msg"><b>Comment</b></label>
        <textarea id="myComment" placeholder="Type comment.." name="msg" required></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="lk-btn" onclick="postComment(); return false">Send</button>
        <button class="lk-btn" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

<div id="commentBox" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: white; color: green;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The created `p` element reference is stored in variable `paragraph`. In order to assign `id` attribute use `paragraph.id` instead of `p.id`.

Since the newly created `p` is not yet appended to the document. So, the statement `document.getElementById('com')` will return null.

```js
document.querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    p.id = "com";

    const val = document.getElementById('myComment').value;
    if (val.length) {
      p.innerHTML = val;
      document.querySelector('div').appendChild(p);
    }

  });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myComment">
<div></div>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

--Edit--

```js
function postComment(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const p = document.createElement('p');
  p.id = "com";
  const val = document.getElementById('myComment').value;
  if (val) {
    p.innerHTML = val;
    document.getElementById('commentBox').appendChild(p);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-popup" id="myForm">
  <form name="commentForm" class="form-container">
    <label for="msg"><b>Comment</b></label>
    <textarea id="myComment" placeholder="Type comment.." name="msg" required></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="lk-btn" onclick="postComment(event); return false">Send</button>
    <button class="lk-btn" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="commentBox" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: white; color: green;"></div>
```

Comment: but can i use .getElementById() instead of .querySelector() for the appendChild(p) ?    Because i have many divs on the page

Comment: @AdegbiteStephen - Yes you can use. Just pass the `id` of your `div` in the `getElementById()`.

Comment: ok! i just updated the code, can you please check it out? because i stil can't get over it

Comment: thanks a lot, this works fine here but once implement in my webpage all the button did was refresh the page. Can you please help with that?

Comment: The buttons are present within the `form` which will post the form and refresh the page. Add `e.preventDefault` to stop it's default action.

Answer (score 0):

I finally did this more easily using p5.js library.
Simply Calling function CreateP() did the trick.